# PHP: SESSIONS causing slowness

Tags: php, performance, session

I have a site that is super fast when the user isn't logged in but slows down dramatically when SESSIONS start to be used after log in. I started using session_write_close(); immediately when possible but it doesn't seem to help.

SESSIONS are set to files in /tmp

Anyone have any ideas on how to improve? I use 8 $_SESSIONs per user. Would lowing that improve performance?

EDIT: To clarify, I am setting 8 different $_SESSION variables, not opening 8 sessions.

EDIT 2: Consolidated my SESSION data into a single array. No improvement. Data is 630 characters. Making it smaller doesn't improve it either.

Comment: you have to and you can use one session to store all the information. no need to do 8 session for single user.

Comment: The number of entries in `$_SESSION[]` doesn't matter that much (if they are in a reasonable limit). The session data is read only once, on `session_start()` and written back to file also just once, when the script ends (or on `session_write_close()`). Some reasons this will take a lot of time could be a very slow file system mounted on `/tmp` (NFS, maybe?), very much information you store in `$_SESSION` (very large arrays?). I would rather investigate the database queries (the code usually runs more queries for logged in users than for anonymous users).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what data you save in your session but it sounds a bit like that you save a lot of big data in your session like whole objects for example. The session is written and read from your hdd. When you have a lot of data in it, it takes a lot of time to load them.

To check if your session has to much data you can make a `var_dump($_SESSION);` to check what data is in your SESSION.

The next thing is that you should place your data on a fast device like an SSD for example not on a NFS filesystem or anything else.

Normally the session system is fast enough.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION); is 630 characters long, displaying my SESSION array data.

Comment: What is if you write only for example 'test' in your session have you the same performance problem?

Comment: Same issue with "test".

Comment: You said that this problem happens if you're logged in perhaps its not your session? You could enable xdebug and make a profile log and look what takes so much time. http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler